# pyhon list reverse slicing excludes 1st item

Tags: python, list, slice, reverse

I would like to go through on a list in reverse order using slices of the list, but I am having trouble to have the 1st (index 0) item of the list on the output.

```
l=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
s=len(l)

for i in range(s):
    print(l[s:i:-1])
```

The output is missing the 1st item of the list:

```
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
 [6, 5, 4, 3]
 [6, 5, 4]
 [6, 5]
 [6]
 []
```

It looks like just a shifting problem, but `i-1` doesn't work as an index  when `i=0`.

The only solution so far I could figure out is ugly:

```
l=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
s=len(l)

for i in range(s):
    if i == 0:
        print(l[s::-1])
    else:
        print(l[s:i-1:-1])
```

Output (what I really wanted):

```
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
 [6, 5, 4, 3]
 [6, 5, 4]
 [6, 5]
 [6]
```

For me it looks like a design failure in python as in a reverse slicing there is no other way to have the 1st item of the list then leaving the field empty, what is a problem when you have a variable there... Tell me how to do it better.

Comment: cough ... list.reverse() ... cough

Comment: yes, I've forgot to mention, I don't want to change the original list or having a copy of it...

Comment: You're making copies anyway.

Comment: yeah, but creating a copy of the entire list (which may be big) or creating a copy of the needed slice in the right time is a big difference. (The code above just a prepared example to show the issue.) Or you meant something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice it in reverse then iterate through the reversed slice

```
l=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
s=len(l)

for i in range(s):
    print(l[::-1][0:s-i])
    
print(l)
```

and the original list wouldn't be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid any checking or slicing by just inverting the list as already suggested.

After defining your list you can do: `l.reverse()` **OR** `l = l[::-1]` (which is the same thing)

For the future, just know that, when slicing lists, the first index is included, but the last isn't. So if you have `mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` doing `mylist[1:3]` will return `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `None`.

```
for i in range(s):
    print(l[: i-1 if i else None : -1])
```